# Is there a difference between these two CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Would the following CSS selectors select the same elements?

```
ul > li[class="a"]  {  }
```

vs

```
ul > li.a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would the following CSS selectors select the same elements?

**No** they don't. Notice how in the below example the last element isn't selected by `ul>li[class="a"]` because that selector will select element having only `a` as a class.

```css
 ul>li.a {
  color: red;
}

 ul>li[class="a"] {
  font-size: 30px;;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li class="a">Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="a b">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
```

Even whitespace count:

```css
ul>li.a {
  color: red;
}

 ul>li[class="a"] {
  font-size: 30px;;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="a">Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="a b">Item 3</li>
    <li class="a ">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Both selectors work the same:

```css
#one ul>li.a {
  color: red;
}

#two ul>li[class="a"] {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <ul>
    <li class="a">Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="a">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <ul>
    <li class="a">Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="a">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```